# Does the Pandas DataFrame.to_sql() function require a subsequent commit()?

Tags: sql, database, pandas, sqlalchemy, commit

The documentation for the Pandas function `to_sql()` available for `DataFrame` objects (see [`to_sql()` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)) does not state that a `commit()` call on the connection is needed (or recommended) to persist the update.

Can I safely assume that `DataFrame.to_sql('table_name', con)` will always automatically commit the changes (like in: `con.commit()`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, at the end of the day it will be commited automatically.

[Pandas calls SQLAlchemy method `executemany`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/sql.py#L1299) (for SQL Alchemy connections):

```
conn.executemany(self.insert_statement(), data_list)
```

[for SQLite connection](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/sql.py#L1389-L1398):

```
def run_transaction(self):
    cur = self.con.cursor()
    try:
        yield cur
        self.con.commit()
    except:
        self.con.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        cur.close()
```

And due to the [SQL Alchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements) `executemany` issues `commit` at the end

Comment: The Pandas function `to_sql()` also works when SQLAlchemy is not installed, in which case it uses `sqlite` (if I understand the documentation correctly). Is the `commit` then also guaranteed?

Comment: I cannot (unambiguously) find the SQLite connections are deprecated in Pandas. There are some discussions about this ([here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6900) and [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6881)), and my understanding is that SQLite connections (via `sqlite3`) are still a supported feature (possibly under the flag 'legacy').

Comment: @TomVerhoeff, yes, that's correct. Sorry for the missleading information. I've mixed it up with the [deprecated `flavor` in to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: The links to the code lines are no longer applicable as they didn't refer to a specific git revision, so it's hard now to follow. It would be nice if we could control commit behavior explicitly through sqlalchemy api as an answer to this.

Comment: I think I don't see an explicit commit in https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/c4489cbfa5f93e69301486e1ef867caed9f4eb9e/pandas/io/sql.py#L724 which is called by Pandas for this. It seems that the python API to sqlite does not auto-commit [if I'm looking in the right place](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions). On the other hand you can't `create_engine(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")` for sqlite, so I'm not sure yet what is the default commit behavior with sqlite using sqlalchemy.