# Pandas to_sql creating table but not inserting data

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle

I am using Oracle, and I am seeing the table created in the schema (albeit all with CLOB columns for VARCHARs).  But no data is being inserted?  The dataframe does have data in it.

```
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:password@host:1521/?service_name=myservice', max_identifier_length=128)
df = get_registrations()
df.to_sql(name='pandas_registrations', con=engine, if_exists='replace', chunksize=1000, schema='ANALYTICS', method=None)
```

I read a commit() is not needed here [Does the Pandas DataFrame.to_sql() function require a subsequent commit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741775/does-the-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-function-require-a-subsequent-commit)

Comment: Well I got it working without con.commit().  I had to replace clobs and set autocommit on the connection.  None of which was described in any examples.  I am not sure which one solved the problem to be honest.

Comment: Apparently commit is not needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741775/does-the-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-function-require-a-subsequent-commit

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem and switching to sqlalchemy instead of cx_Oracle as the engine helped in my scenario.

Comment: I am using sqlalchemy create_engine, just with the oracle driver?

Comment: SQLAlchemy uses cx_Oracle!

Comment: So what would my driver string look like?