# Force not commit on df.to_sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I need to use pandas df.to_sql without auto commit at the end. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using SQLAlchemy? If so, SQLAlchemy will always commit automatically (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47742714/9501624))
You could however use the [engine.begin](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.begin) context manager to roll back any commits upon failure:

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    df.to_sql(name= 'test1',schema='test', con=conn)
```